# How to get distance matrix from Adjacency matrix matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, networking, matrix, logic

I have adjacency matrix let it be called A size n*n

Where `A(k,j)=A(j,k)=1` if `k,j` are connected in 1 hop.

Now it look that if I take

```
Dist=double(A)*double(A)>0 %getting all two hops connectivity
Dist=double(Dist)*double(A)>0 %getting all three hops connectivity 
Dist=double(Dist)*double(A)>0 %getting all four hops connectivity
```

Is this right at all?

I tried it with some simple graphs and it looks legit

Can I use this fact to create distance matrix?

Where distance matrix will show the minimum number of hops from j to k

P.S:

If it legit I will be happy to understand why it is right, did now find info in Google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly right: the entries of the adjacency matrix gives you the connections between vertices. Powers of the adjacency matrix are concatenating walks. The `ij`*th* entry of the `k`*th* power of the adjacency matrix tells you the *number of walks* of length `k` from vertex `i` to vertex `j`.

This can be quite easily proven by induction.

Be aware that the powers of the adjacency matrix count the number of `i→j` walks, not paths (a walk can repeat vertices, while a path cannot). So, to create a distance matrix you need to iterativerly power your adjacency matrix, and as soon as a `ij`*th* element is non-zero you have to assign the distance `k` in your distance matrix.

Here is a try:

```
% Adjacency matrix
A = rand(5)>0.5

D = NaN(A);
B = A;
k = 1;
while any(isnan(D(:)))

    % Check for new walks, and assign distance
    D(B>0 & isnan(D)) = k;

    % Iteration
    k = k+1;
    B = B*A;
end

% Now D contains the distance matrix
```

Note that if you are searching for the shortest paths in a graph, you can also use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Finally, note that this is completely comptatible with [sparse matrices](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html). As adjacency matrices are often good candidates for sparse matrices, it may be highly beneficial in terms of performance.

Best,

Comment: thx for the explanation, didnt know about the number of walks, well i didnt use your code so cant say if it is solid but thx m8!!