# Computing the distance matrix from an adjacency matrix in python

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix, distance-matrix

Write a code that produces the distance matrix from a graph (graph theory), the code should use the adjacency matrix and cannot use any functions from NetworkX module, apart from networkx.adjacency_matrix().

I understand the process of how the distance matrix works. My theory of how the adjacency matrix is involved is that it takes an element that connects two nodes and adds the distance up. For example, lets say i have nodes A, B and C. A is connected to B, and B is connected to C. The distance between two connected nodes is 1. So the distance from A to C would be 2.

My only problem is how i can implement this into a code so that it creates a distance matrix for any given graph.

Thank you for any help, sorry if my explanation is unclear, please let me know if you would like me to clarify anything.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164512/4743630) is a solution in Matlab that you could adapt. Or look at the source code of the NetworkX module to understand how they calculate the adjacency matrix.

Comment: There is an SO sistersite named stats for these type of questions ;p Check it [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and see all others as well ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Check if the below code helps.

```
#G is a networkX graph.
def get_actual_distance_between_two_nodes(G, i, j):
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G, seed=random_seed)
    sp = nx.shortest_path(G, i, j)
    edges_set = [[sp[i], sp[i+1]] for i in range(len(sp)-1)]

    distance_list = []
    for edge in edges_set:
        start_node = edge[0]
        end_node = edge[1]

        x1 = pos[start_node][0]
        y1 = pos[start_node][1]
        x2 = pos[end_node][0]
        y2 = pos[end_node][1]

        distance = math.dist([x1,y1], [x2,y2])
        distance_list.append(distance)

    return (sum(distance_list)) 
    
def nodes_connected(G, u, v):
    return u in G.neighbors(v)

def create_distance_matrix(G, nodes_list):
    distance_matrix_custom = []
    for i in range(len(nodes_list)):
        current_node = nodes_list[i]
        #print("Current Node: --->", current_node)
        list_of_distance = []
        for j in range(len(nodes_list)):
            target_node = nodes_list[j]
            #print("Target Node: --->", target_node)
            
            if(current_node == target_node):
                actual_distance = 0
            elif(G.has_edge(current_node, target_node)):
                actual_distance = get_actual_distance_between_two_nodes(G, current_node, target_node)                
            else:
                #actual_distance = float('inf')
                actual_distance = 10000000000
            list_of_distance.append(actual_distance)
        distance_matrix_custom.append(list_of_distance)

    return distance_matrix_custom
        
distance_matrix_custom = create_distance_matrix(G, nodes_list)
```

Comment: From the OP's description, it is not permitted to use any functions from `networkx` except `adjacency_matrix()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).