# Find pairs of nodes that are between 2 and 3 hops away from each other

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a large graph with about 50,000 nodes and 2,000,000 edges. I need to find all pairs of nodes that are between 2 and 3 hops away from each other.

The simplest (and dirty) solution is first to create combinatorial expansion and then check each pair of nodes:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

g = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n=5000, p=0.05)
L = list(G.nodes())
# Create a complete graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(L)
G.add_edges_from(itertools.combinations(L, 2))
```

However, when I try to create a complete graph with 45,000 nodes and 2 million edges, I ran out of RAM.

Is there any other solution that could inspect a large graph in a reasonable time? Thanks for any advice or pointer.

Comment: What is the format of the lists of nodes and edges?

Comment: @gst Input format is an edgelist.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be hard to build an adjacency matrix out of it. Basically you take the n-th power of the adjacency matrix and if it's non-zero a n-hop-path exists between the nodes. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164012/how-to-get-distance-matrix-from-adjacency-matrix-matlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your edge list and convert it to an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), see [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146892/numpy-scipy-build-adjacency-matrix-from-weighted-edgelist) for how to do it memory-efficiently with `scipy.sparse`. Then use `numpy.linalg.matrix_power` to raise the adjacency matrix to 2nd power. For each entry in the squared matrix, if the entry is non-zero, there exists a path of length two between the nodes (in fact the entry gives you the number of paths of length 2 between the nodes). See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164012/how-to-get-distance-matrix-from-adjacency-matrix-matlab):

> Powers of the adjacency matrix are concatenating walks. The `ij`th entry of the `k`th power of the adjacency matrix tells you the number of walks of length `k` from vertex `i` to vertex `j`.

You can do the same for paths of length 3, by raising it to the 3rd power.