# how to find all the nodes that are 4 steps away from the source node?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

What is the fastest way to find all the nodes that are 4 steps away from the source node within a graph? use by pandas or networkx

I am currently running in a loop across the network and calculating distances between all points to the target point .
then filtering the relevant nodes

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct built in algo for this purpose but you can use [networkx.shortest_path_length()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html#shortest-path-length) to get all the nodes and their distance from source node. and then you can filter the paths.

```
# import networkx as nx
# G=nx.karate_club_graph()
nx.shortest_path_length(G,source=0)
```

And you can explore other options (Numpy and Scipy) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447119/find-pairs-of-nodes-that-are-between-2-and-3-hops-away-from-each-other)

Comment: it work if i put target in instead of source .
Thank you